# How do I conditionally configure a @Bean when the code is using a builder pattern?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, retrofit

I'm using the [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library to make client calls.  In some environments, I want to encrypt *some of* my traffic a certain way.  In other environments, I don't.  Normally I'd do this with a property configuration or a Spring profile, but this code looks like this:

```
        //This is an @Bean method
        new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setConverter(new JacksonConverter(this.jacksonObjectMapper))
        .setErrorHandler(new RetrofitErrorHandler())
        .setLog(new RetrofitLogback())
        .setLogLevel(logLevel)
        .setEndpoint(host)
        .setClient(sslClient()) //sometimes do this, sometimes don't do this
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .build()
```

There are many places in our code that conditionally need `sslClient()` and some that should never use the `sslClient`.  Does Spring have a way to configure this conveniently?

The most naive way to do this is to find all this retrofit setup and wrap some of it in an `if` statement.  But maybe there is a much cleaner way to refactor this code that has nothing to do with Spring.

Comment: May be you can get a dummy implementation of `sslClient`? So configure it always, but sometimes use dummy client and sometime real client.

Comment: @Nikem yeah I was thinking about that, too.  That could be an option.  Similar vein: The sslClient has a conditional in it that either works or is a noop.

Comment: can you use AOP? intercept all calls to `new RestAdapter.Builder()` and add sslClient as needed.